# zeros and negatives wont display

Tags: crystal-reports, zero, negative-number

I have a report that has multiple 0 values, but instead of showing the zero, crystal shows a blank space instead. then, 2 columns over i have a field that should subtract another field from that 0 and be negative, but since the zero field is empty, it wont and the difference comes up empty two. Any idea how to fix this?

this is my code snippet for the field that has the zero:

```
if {fullmain.initres} > 0 
then {fullmain.initres}
else 0.00
```

this is my code snippet for the field that should show the difference :

```
if {@RESERVE} > 0 then 
{@RESERVE}-{@AMOUNT}
else 0 - {@AMOUNT}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the field`({fullmain.initres} and {@RESERVE})` right next to your formula and check if it is returning `a null value, in this case blank`. If so you might need to add and `or` to your `if statement` saying

```
if isnull({fullmain.initres} <= 0 or {fullmain.initres})
then 0.00
else {fullmain.initres}

if isnull({@RESERVE} or {@RESERVE} <= 0)
then 0 - {@AMOUNT}
else {@RESERVE}-{@AMOUNT}
```

Comment: You need to perform the `isnull()` as the first thing you do with a field, otherwise the entire formula will not be evaluated. For example, if `{fullmain.initres}` is null and it tries the comparison `{fullmain.initres}>0` first then the whole formula will just stop.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on @Ryan's(Thank you for that clarification) comment.